# Lotus Notes - Cursor blinks / flashes while scanning inbox

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a bot that is scanning my inbox periodically for specific emails. Whenever the code below is firing the cursor blinks and flashes when the cursor is over the Lotus Notes UI. Google returned about 5 results for my search and none of them seemed to address this issue. It's not preventing my program from working but it does look pretty bad aesthetically. Anyone out there have any ideas? Thanks!

*I also tagged this as C# to get more eyes looking at it. I'd prefer a vb.net solution but C# is welcome and appreciated as well.

```
    Dim NS As Object = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Dim NDB As Object = NS.GetDatabase("", "")
    If NDB.IsOpen = False Then NDB.Openmail()
    Dim NV As Object = NDB.GetView("($Inbox)")
    NV.refresh()
    Dim ND As Object = NV.GetFirstDocument
    Dim aItems As Array
    Dim dInfo As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim EmailCount As Integer = NV.entrycount
    Dim iCurrent As Integer = 0
    Dim EmailDate As DateTime
    Dim Subject As String, Body As String, sFrom As String
    Do
        iCurrent += 1
        aItems = ND.Items
        dInfo = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To aItems.Length - 1
            If Not dInfo.ContainsKey(aItems(i).name) Then
                dInfo.Add(aItems(i).name, aItems(i).text)
            End If
        Next
        EmailDate = CDate(dInfo("DeliveredDate"))
        Subject = dInfo("Subject")
        Body = dInfo("Body")
        sFrom = dInfo("From")
        If NV.GetNextDocument(ND) Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        ND = NV.GetNextDocument(ND)
    Loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted this as too local / unlikely to help anyone in the future. If this had been answered in the past it would be helping me right now!

Comment: I agree.  It should not be voted down.  This confusion between the two sets of classes is fairly common, and yes, there are still people using and programming for Lotus Notes and Domino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Notes.NotesSession` class is an OLE class, which means that it interacts with the Notes UI.

You should be using the COM version of the class instead, which is `Lotus.NotesSession`

Comment: I tried switching it to Lotus.NotesSession and the Lotus Notes UI crashed. I'll see if I can find out where it crashed

Comment: Ok it crashed on this line: Dim NDB As Object = NS.GetDatabase("", ""). I'll try supplying the Server and NSF mail file. *Edit: No luck. Any ideas?

Comment: With the COM classes, you need to call NotesSession.Initialize().  See here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html

Comment: Initialize requires a password correct? The nice thing about the way I'm doing it now is that it requires no password or user interaction. The downfall, of course, is the flickering cursor. So my only 2 choices are prompt for a lotus password or deal with the blinking cursor?

Comment: There is another choice, but it requires the users to change a setting in their Notes client setup to allow external programs to access their Notes data without entering a password.  This setting does raise some security risks, so you would need to think carefully about whether or not to use it.  In Notes 8, the setting is available under File - Security - User Security on the "Security Basics - Who You Are" tab, with the label "Don't prompt for password from other Notes-based programs".

Comment: There is also a way to write a Notes C API Extenstion Manager add-in that hooks Notes authentication, which would allow you to provide avoid the password prompt only for your program -- but this is a lot of work, and since you'll have to store the password somewhere (encrypted, of course) it is not entirely risk free.  And you would have to provide users with a way to enter the password the first time they use your code, and any time they change their Notes password.  So while I mention this for completeness, I really don't recommend it.

Comment: Yeah good info. So it sounds like there is no relatively easy way to get rid of the blinking cursor without user interaction of some sort. Is there a cursor change windows api message like WM_CURSORCHANGE or something that can be hooked and cancelled? Maybe while the program scans the inbox it could lock it on the arrow and release it after it's done scanning?

Comment: There probably is a way to get to the cursor -- but I'm not familiar with it.  And in any case, I think it could be a bit risky.  If you muck with the cursor, and an error occurs that for some reason you don't catch, then the cursor could remain in whatever state you put it in.

Comment: I tried Public Declare Function SetCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal hCursor As Long) As Long, to no avail. Oh well. THanks for your help